# Object Oriented Features in OO languages

Tags: java, oop

These are OO concepts:

- Inheritance
- Polymorphism
- Abstraction
- Encapsulation

Now, can you say that each OO programming language implements all those techniques? Or, otherwise, what is common amongst all the OO languages? For example, comparing Java and javascript. It is not a stupid question. For example, some languages, for example Java, does not allow multiple inheritance when Scala does. So, Java is like not complete OO language. I just wondering whether saying that each OO language is, for example, polymorphic is completely true or not.
Cheers

Comment: none of the object-oriented languages uses _abstaction_ =)

Comment: are interested in specific language ?  (java compared to something else of example)

Comment: The languages don't implement it. The developers do.

Comment: @ivanovic: I disagree. Abstraction is achieved using polymorphism.

Comment: tell us the story, what problem should this question solve ?

Comment: @Azodious i just made fun of typo, what is your point?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

simple answer: NO.

here is a nice article that points out .. how the definition for a "real" OO language.. can not be done.

> There are different relationships between object orientation and computer languages: support of OO, ubiquitous use of OO, and enforcement of OO.
>   Again, I'd recommend some effort to be unambiguous: e.g. "Java supports OO but doesn't use it everywhere", "SmallTalk uses OO everywhere, even for integers", "Java enforces OO by making you put all code into methods", etc.
>   [source](http://c2.com/cgi/wiki?ObjectOrientedProgrammingLanguage)

some of this OOP concepts are created AFTER most of the languages and in there later versions .. there is different level of support for them.

It really depends of the main principles of the language, witch concepts should be supported or required.

[Languages with object-oriented features](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_object-oriented_programming_languages) (over 50)

Answer (score 0):

For a starter, I definitely disagree with

> ...for example Java, does not allow multiple inheritance when Scala
>   does. So, Java is like not complete OO language.

If you are going to judge how OO is a language based on another language's features then I guess you will find no "complete" OO language. What I think you should do is track the OO roots and check how much a given language adheres to that paradigm. A really good reading is Alan Kay's [Early history of Smalltalk](http://stephane.ducasse.free.fr/FreeBooks/SmalltalkHistoryHOPL.pdf), where he explains the basics of the paradigm. Based on that you can later divide pure OO languages, where everything is modeled as an object (e.g. Smalltalk or Self) and hybrid languages, that while supporting OO concepts, do not fully adhere to the paradigm (e.g. PHP). Also, there are pure OO languages both class-based and [prototype-based](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prototype-based_programming), so e.g. having multiple inheritance or not doesn't define if a language is OO.

HTH